# How to call function of one Activity from other Activity or service?

Tags: android, class, android-activity, function-call

I need to call some functions from one activity. But when I do that, it gives null pointer... error.
I am using this as my example,
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-text-to-speech-application.html

Please see line 38, says tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

So, if I have changed the code like this...

```
public class TTA extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

... ... ... ...

 public void MYCall()
 {
 tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
 }

... ... ...
}
```

and then call this my call from another activity, like this,

```
TTA tta = new TTA();
tta.MYCall();
```

Shouldn't it work?  It doesnt, however when MYCall() is called from within the TTA class it works.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what's going on, as you haven't provided much code to examine.

Are you doing set-up for the text-to-speech object in Activity lifecycle methods? Those will not get called if you simply instantiate the Activity using `new TTA()`, so most likely your Text-To-Speech object isn't yet correctly initialized.

However: I would suggest re-arranging your code so that Text-To-Speech related methods are not coupled with a particular Activity, since you'll be using it in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `speak()` or `tta.MYCall()` until `onInit()` is called.

Therefore, running your two lines of code is not likely to work all the time.

You need something like this or re-arrange your code:

```
TTA tta = new TTA();
while (!tta.isInitialized())
{
  try
  {
  Thread.sleep(100);
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e)
  {}
}
tta.MYCall();
```